# Should a Connection String include a local instance or IP Address

Tags: sql-server, performance, ip, web-config

We are optimizing our Web System and I then had a thought.

In the web system's Web.config, should the connection string include an IP Address to the local SQL Server or rather an Instance? Will there be a performance difference?

I was thinking that with an IP address a formal IP or TCP connection would be established and perhaps with a local Instance reference a different protocol is executed?

I couldn't find related information on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Using an instance name such as `SomeMachine\SomeInstance` means the client needs to look up the port using SQL Browser.

For best performance it would probably be best to use an IP address and port number. You must [set a static port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-ver16) for the instance, otherwise it won't connect.

Ideally use a DNS name rather than an IP address, otherwise you keep having to change it. So you want something like `SomeMachineDnsName.YourDomain.com,1433`.

Comment: Thank you. That is how it currently is configured.